# Is UPDATE and CONNECT BY supported?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sql-update, execute-immediate

I created a procedure using `execute immediate`, when I debug and step over to `execute immediate` in this procedure, it shows the following message :

> An Oracle exception has occurred in your code. If the code contains an exception handler, you can continuing stepping through the handler; otherwise, the error message will display and the next step will exit execution.

and then I take out the query, the query in execute immediate is:

```
update mstarea 
set '||v_temp_position||' = :pid 
where areacode = :pnewarea1 
connect by prior areacode = areaparent 
start with areacode in (:pnewarea1, :pnewarea2);
```

and I try to execute/compile that query, it has an error like this:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Is `connect by prior` supported with `update`?

This is my procedure, and the error is below `update mstarea` when it reaches `execute immediate`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure PROC1(pid in varchar2, pposition in varchar2, pnewarea1 in varchar2, pnewarea2 in varchar2)
is 
v_error_message varchar2(255);
v_temp_position varchar2(25 byte);
v_sql_statement varchar2(255);
n_count_role number;
cursor cuser is
    select userid from master.mstuser where id = pid; 
begin
    for cdata in cuser
    loop
        begin
            select count(role) into n_count_role from mstmapping where role = pposition;
            if n_count_role > 0 then
            begin
                ..........
                if pnewarea1 = 'ALL' then
                    ..........
                else
                    ..........
                    ------------------- update mstarea -------------------
                    if pposition in ('A', 'B') then
                        select 'AB' into v_temp_position from dual;
                    else
                        select pposition into v_temp_position from dual;
                    end if;
                    v_sql_statement := 'update mstarea set '||v_temp_position||' = :pid where areacode = :pnewarea1 connect by prior areacode = areaparent start with areacode in (:pnewarea1, :pnewarea2)';
                    execute immediate v_sql_statement using pid, pnewarea1, pnewarea1, pnewarea2; -- advice from @Rene
                    ------------------------------------------------------
                    ..........
                    end;
                end if;
            end;
            end if;
            exception
            when others then
            ..........
        rollback;
        end;
    commit;
    exit when cuser%notfound;
    end loop;
end;
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: thanks for editing my question @Jonny

Comment: Is `connect by prior` supported with `update`? - no it's not: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the information sir!

Answer (score 1):

Zooming in on just this part of the code:

```
v_sql_statement := 'update mstarea 
                    set '||v_temp_position||' = :pid 
                    where areacode = :pnewarea1 
                    connect by prior areacode = areaparent 
                    start with areacode in (:pnewarea1, :pnewarea2)';

execute immediate v_sql_statement                         
using pid, pnewarea1, pnewarea2;
```

You have four variables in your query. Although two of them have the same name you have to provide a value for each position. To fix this use pnewarea1 twice:

```
execute immediate v_sql_statement                         
    using pid, pnewarea1, pnewarea1, pnewarea2;
```

-- Edit----

Conclusion is that `update .. connect by prior` is not supported in Oracle.

Comment: oh,  ok, thanks for the advice @Rene, i've added that parameter but still had a same error.
is it from the statement? or something?

Comment: Without the actual error it's hard to give an answer. Pick up the query and run in it SQLplus.

Comment: ok @Rene,
when i take out that query, the error message is:

`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

am i wrong?

Comment: And what are the values for pid, pnewarea1, pnewarea1, pnewarea2? Do they all have a value? If not that might be your problem.

Comment: Maybe the question is: Is update and connect by prior supported?

Comment: yeah they all have a value. that's the point! how connecting `update` with `connect by prior` thanks @Rene. Sorry, i got confused here. Soo, i still can't fix this. But, many thanks for the advices :)